# AngularFire $loaded never fires

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularfire

I am trying to do something which should be fairly simple - load in an object from my Firebase DB and assign it to a variable in my controller. This worked perfectly before, when I was using Firebase functions (see commented out code), but I want to use 3-way binding so am trying to do the same thing in AngularFire.

The $loaded event doesn't seem to fire, as the planner object (nor the 'You Are Here') never prints to the console. The user.uid string prints to the console as expected, and the commented out code works perfectly. Thanks in advance for your help.

(Side question: In the commented out code, I make use of evalAsync to ensure the forms on the web page actually update when the information is retrieved - is this good practice?)

My controller:

```
   firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
            console.log("Currently logged in user...");
            console.log(user.uid);
            $scope.user = user;

           var ref = firebase.database().ref('planners/' + $scope.user.uid);
           var planner = $firebaseObject(ref);

           planner.$loaded().then(function() {
              console.log("You are here")
              console.log(planner)
           })
           .catch(function(error) {
              console.log(error)
           })
           // firebase.database().ref('planners/' + $scope.user.uid).on('value', function(response) {
           //    if (response.val() != null) {
           //       $scope.$evalAsync(function() {
           //          $scope.planner = response.val();
           //       })
           //    }
           // });
        }
        else {
           console.log('No user logged in')
           $state.go('login')
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing this...

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
```

to this...

```
$firebaseAuth().$onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
```

see documentation for more information

https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md#onauthstatechangedcallback-context

Answer (score 0):

As @Aaron Saunders suggested, you should use the AngularFire auth object since it is better integrates with Angular (updates `$scope`s, trigger `$digest`s etc.).

The code you had before worked because of the `$evalAsync` which fires a `$digest` if one isn't running (the `$digest` loop is the magician that binds the data between the model and view).

What you should actually do is use AngularFire to bind data. They also provide "3-way binding" (model-view-database) by utilizing `$bindTo`.

As you can see in the `$firebaseObject` [docs](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md#firebaseobject) the data will sync from server to client automagically, but if you want to save local changes back to the server, you should use [`$save`](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md#save) or [`$bindTo`](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md#firebaseobject).

Code fix suggestion:

```
$firebaseAuth().$onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    // By using `$firebaseAuth` this function will be called in a `$digest` so all changes will be bound
    if (user) {
        console.log("Currently logged in user...");
        console.log(user.uid);
        $scope.user = user;

        var ref = firebase.database().ref('planners/' + $scope.user.uid);
        // `$destroy` previous bindings
        if ($scope.planner && angular.isFunction($scope.planner.$destroy)) {
            $scope.planner.$destroy();
        }
        $scope.planner = $firebaseObject(ref);

        // planner.$loaded().then(function() {
        //    // This code will happen only after `$digest` since its promise is relied on the `$q` service
        //    console.log("You are here")
        //    console.log(planner)
        // })
        // .catch(function(error) {
        //    console.log(error)
        // })
        // firebase.database().ref('planners/' + $scope.user.uid).on('value', function(response) {
        //    if (response.val() != null) {
        //       $scope.$evalAsync(function() {
        //          $scope.planner = response.val();
        //       })
        //    }
        // });
    } else {
        console.log('No user logged in');
        $scope.user = null;
        if ($scope.planner && angular.isFunction($scope.planner.$destroy)) {
            $scope.planner.$destroy();
        }
        $state.go('login');
    }
});
```